# How to prevent selecting value while enter key press in react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am trying to achieve to prevent the enter key selection while user has nothing typed and press the enter key. In current situation when user click on `react-select` and hit the enter key then its selecting the first value from the drop down, where user has nothing typed but still its selection first value from drop down. Is anyone has any idea to prevent this functionality.

It should only select when user type something in input box and select or hit enter key.

here is the screen short where user has nothing typed and press enter key then its selecting first value.

[image]

here is code:

```
  import React from 'react';
  import Select from 'react-select';

  class CreateSelectOption extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        selected: this.props.options,
        questionsCount: props.questionsCount,
        inputValue: '',
    }
    this.processQuestions = this.processQuestions.bind(this);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (newProps.questionsCount.length > 0) {
        this.setState({
            questionsCount: newProps.questionsCount
        })
    }
}

onChange = (e, props) =>{
    this.props.onChange(e, props.technology, props.id, props.type, props.noc, props.dataTech, props.dataType);
}

onInputValueChange = inputValue => {
    this.setState({ inputValue: this.allowOnlyOneSpace(inputValue) });
  };

allowOnlyOneSpace = str => {
    return str.endsWith(" ") ? str.trim() + " " : str.trim();
};

render() {
   
    const customStyles = {
        control: (styles, state) => ({
            ...styles,
            borderRadius: '1px', // default border color
            boxShadow: 'none', // no box-shadow
            color: '#007bff',
            height: '27px',
            minHeight: '30px'
        }),
        singleValue: (styles, state) => ({
            ...styles,
            color: '#007bff',
            top: '42%'
          }),
        dropdownIndicator: (styles, state) => ({
        ...styles,
        padding: "6px"
        }),
        menuPortal: base => ({ ...base, zIndex: 9999, fontSize: '12px' })
}
    const { selectedTech }=this.props;
    const selectedVal = selectedTech ? { value: selectedTech , label: selectedTech } : null;
    return(
    <Select
        className="select-width select-color"
        menuPortalTarget={document.body}
        styles={customStyles}
        value={selectedVal}
        onChange={(e) => { this.onChange(e, this.props) }}
        options={props.technologyArray && props.technologyArray.map(t => ({ value: t, label: t }))}
        openMenuOnClick={true}
        placeholder="Please select tech"
        components={{ IndicatorSeparator: () => null }}
        inputValue={this.state.inputValue}
        onInputChange={this.onInputValueChange}
        disabled={this.state.inputValue.length === 0}
        />
    )
}
```

}
export default CreateSelectOption;

Comment: Is it like this? https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/4042

Answer (score 0):

**UPD**  `options={this.state.inputValue.length === 0 ? [] : colourOptions}`

Comment: here is jsfiddle link you can check by adding your code.  

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandboxer-example-izdon

Answer (score 0):

try these properties

```
    openMenuOnFocus={false}
    openMenuOnClick={false}
```

and I guess (can't check that right now though) that also this is working too (if selectedVal is present, then it turns to true else false)

```
    openMenuOnFocus={selectedVal}
    openMenuOnClick={selectedVal}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. its works once user type but once clear then again drop down is still open then user can press enter key and again first value will be selected.